# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: after calling procedure from java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Hi I have problem with calling store procedure.
when i am trying to call my procedure from my following java code

```
connection = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection(dataBaseURL, serverName, portNumber, sid, username, password);

callable = connection.prepareCall("{call SCHEMA_RESTORE.restore()}");

callable.executeUpdate();
..................................
```

I am getting this Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

PLS-00201: identifier 'SCHEMA_RESTORE.RESTORE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:573)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1891)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:1093)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java:2047)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java:1940)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2709)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:589)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:656)
```

My Prodedure is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SCHEMA_RESTORE IS 
  PROCEDURE backup (pbRecreateBackupTable IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE)
    IS
      TableAlreadyExists EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (TableAlreadyExists, -955);
      nCount NUMBER;
      CURSOR cTables IS SELECT tbls.table_name tbl, SUBSTR(tbls.table_name,4) name FROM user_tables tbls, FT_T_TBDF tbdf
        WHERE tbls.table_name NOT LIKE gsPrefix || '%' AND tbls.table_name NOT LIKE 'FT_CFG%' AND tbls.table_name NOT IN ('FT_WF_APEV','FT_WF_WFTJ','FT_WF_WFTN','FT_WF_WFNP','FT_WF_WFNV','FT_WF_WFIO','FT_WF_WFGV','FT_WF_WFND','FT_WF_WFDF','EXCEPTIONS','TESTDSFP') and tbls.table_name NOT LIKE 'FT_LOG%'
          AND tbdf.tbl_id(+) = SUBSTR(tbls.table_name,-4) AND tbdf.tbl_desc NOT LIKE '%Note: This table is obsolete%';
BEGIN

        RAISE;
    END;
  END LOOP; 
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END backup;
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message says that SCHEMA_RESTORE.RESTORE cannot be found. There are several possible causes:

- The package (and procedure) are in a different schema, e.g. you compiled it as user A but are trying to call them as user B.
- You don't have the access right to execute procedures from the package. Thus it becomes invisible.
- You have defined the procedure in the package body, but haven't declared it in the package header.

A further problem I can see are the parentheses. If you call a procedure without arguments, the prentheses shoul be omitted:

```
{ call SCHEMA_RESTORE.restore }
```

Answer (score 4):

It comes when you make a procedure in one user and connect the db in another.
To solve this issue try this

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON procedureName TO username
```

Otherwise connect with correct username which you using

Answer (score 1):

Did the procedure compile successfully ? Also check if you can see it via some editor (PL/SQL dev ?) under the schema

or you may use this to see if it is there -

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE object_name = '%your proc name%';
```